# byte order independent I/O in c

Tags: c, io

I have to read 4 byte blocks from input ( see below).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
unsigned char input[4][8] = {{'A', 'B','C','D','A','B','C','D'},
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D','A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D','A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D','A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}
};
unsigned char output[4][2];
int main(void) {
    int  line_num;
    unsigned int *ptr=(unsigned int*)&input;
    for (line_num=0; line_num < 4*2; line_num++) {
        unsigned char *arr1 = ( (unsigned char*)ptr );
        printf("==> line_num %d: %c%c%c%c\n", line_num, *arr1, *(arr1+1), *(arr1+2), *(arr1+3));
        ptr++;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Right now I am just using an integer pointer to read 4 bytes and a char* pointer to iterate within 4 byte block; That  works for big endian but wouldn't work for little endian. Is there a more generic and order independent approach to this in "C"?

Comment: It depends on platform, but generally the `ntohs`/`htons` and `ntohl`/`htonl` function pairs (that is traditionally used in network programming) should work fine. There are also other similar functions, but none that are portable between systems really. But if you have an array of bytes (characters) there's no byte-ordering issues really... If you send it as is it will be received the right order.

Comment: Joachim is right on all fronts; especially, do not re-invent the ntoh*/hton* functions. Just to ask the same as Joachim, but more specific: What was the reason for you to use an integer pointer? (And consider that an integer can have a different length!)

Comment: To emphasize what @PeterSchneider says - the sizes of `int`,`short`, and `long` along with their unsigned counterparts are not fixed - they can and do vary even on the same platform if you compile using different memory models.  Pointers, too.  If you want to use a specific size integer value, **use a specific size integer variable**:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

Comment: You still haven't indicated whether you indeed need an integer value or whether you just used a 32 bit data type to conveniently read 4 bytes (which I would discourage). The answers totally hinge on that.

Comment: I don't really need an integer value, but it's a 4x faster to read it as an integer value

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not interpret a char buffer as it were an unsigned int. You must copy the value to a valid object.

To avoid the endianness problem, decide which order will you use in the transmission and then the conversion becomes independent of the platform.

Assuming the data in the transmission is little endian( and the values are sensible )you obtain the values like this: ( This works on any platform )

```
unsigned char data[4] = ... ;

uint32_t value = (data[0] << 0) | (data[1] << 8) | (data[2] << 16) | (data[3] << 24);
```

And vice-versa if it is in big endian.

Comment: Proper alignment of data assumed, why would you not just point an int pointer to the 4-byte segments (legal even with strict aliasing beause one of the aliases is a char pointer -- exactly this use case is why the exemption exists) and do a ntohl (which will be optimal, correct and a NOP on little endian architectures)?

Comment: @PeterSchneider You don't understand the how strict aliasing works. Here it is in plain English: char* can point to any object. But not anything, in this case int*, can point to to char* object. The only thing that can point to char* object is char*( ignoring void* and unsigned char*  for a moment ). char* and int* are not compatible. You cannot point an int* to a char object, regardless of alignment.

Comment: Ah. I thought aliasing with char is bidirectional. Re-reading 6.5/7 in n1570 supports what you say though. But this invalidates all direct access to hardware data etc. through structure overlays. No wonder Linus rants against the idea (cf. http://www.mail-archive.com/linux-btrfs@vger.kernel.org/msg01647.html). Btw, strictly spoken "_pointing_ to a char object" is not forbidden, alignment assumed (6.3.2.3/7: "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type.") _Accessing_ is the problem.

Comment: You cannot point an int* to a char object, regardless of alignment? How's about casting - is casting like (int*) (char*) illegal?

Comment: @user270398 Yes. Casting doesn't change the fact that you are breaking the rules. It just silences the compiler.

Comment: What kind of problems can i see resulting from this (int*)(char*) cast?

Comment: @user270398 Undefined behavior can do anything: program that runs incorrectly, creating security vulnerabilities, causing crashes,  wiping the hard drive, ...